# Textarea text show slowly after css animation on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, ios, css, css-animations

I have a problem after doing a css animation.
I'm testing my website on reals iPhone 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 (not with chrome dev tools, it works well on it).

this is the important part of my page

```
<div class="show-conv" onclick="js to add the .active class"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="conv">
    <div class="message">Hello</div>
    <div class="message">Hi</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>Send</button>
</div>

/** CSS **/
.list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.conv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 100%;
    transition: left .25s ease;
}
.conv.active {
   left: 0;
}
```

If I don't do any animation and show the .conv element in a first place I can type on my textarea without any trouble
But if not, (so it means that I have my .show-conv button that add the ".active" class to the .conv element to show it) when I will be typing within my textarea the text will appear after about 5 to 10 seconds.

Everything works fine with an input type="text"...

I could use an input type text instead but I don't want to do tricky stuff without understanding what's happening.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

I use angularjs so my textarea has a ng-model
so if I add an input text with the same model and I hide it with visibility:hidden in css, my text show normally in my textarea...

Comment: Have you tried putting the class `conv` on the `textarea` instead of the `div`?

Comment: Well, there is messages above the textarea I should have put it in my exemple.

Comment: What happens if you take the `width` and `height` off of the `.conv` rule?

Comment: Still not working well.

Comment: Without a way to test this myself all I can give you is some ways to try to solve it, like suggesting removing the width and height. Sometimes back in the day % dimensions caused problems on some rendering engines, try to remove them all and use px dimensions. Try to explicitly define a size (width, height) for your text area and everything else that might be causing the "render" to wait for that transition to be over. It's possible that lack of explicit dimensions and/or % dimensions are causing the render to take a long time in calculating and completing that transition.